# Updating LXML attributes with values stored in CSV file

Tags: python, xml, pandas, csv, lxml

I am able to loop through an assets.csv file and create XML snippets for each row, however I'm attempting to populate each sigEquipment ID attribute with the ID value from each row, when iterating over it.

Below is a snapshot of the assets.csv

```
ID,CODE,EL,TR,DIR,MIL,X,Y,Z,DESC
30734,X1,CC1,8100,,008+0249 (9-1497),518169.12,185128.27,37.52,
31597,X10,BB1,9100,,008+0286 (9-1460),518151.38,185157.1,36.7,XXX
```

and the code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree as et

df = pd.read_csv('assets.csv', sep=',')

root = et.Element('SchemeData', xmlns='boo')

for row in df:
    equipment= et.SubElement(root, 'Equipment')
    sigEquipment = et.SubElement(equipment, 'SigEquipment', ID='', name='')
    sigEquipment.set('ID', str(df['ID'].iloc[0]))


print(et.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

I'm unsure how to correctly code this part `sigEquipment.set('ID', str(df['ID'].iloc[0]))` How would one be able to populate the correct ID for each row.

currently I get

```
<SchemeData xmlns="boo">
    <Equipment>
        <SigEquipment fileUID="30734" name=""/>
    </Equipment>
    <Equipment>
        <SigEquipment fileUID="30734" name=""/>
    </Equipment>
</SchemeData>
```

Thank you for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, so let me go through this line by line.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.read_csv("assets.csv")
```

If you look at the [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) definition then you see that this function returns a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). If you want to iterate over it, then you’ll have to specify *how* and that will define *what* your iteration sees. In this case, using [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) is useful and returns a two-tuple of the row index and the row data:

```
>>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     print(index, row["ID"])
... 
0 30734
1 31597
```

As you can see, columns can be indexed using their names (as defined by the first line of the CSV file). Now let’s put this all together:

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.Element("SchemeData", xmlns="Boo")
>>> for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     equipment = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, "Equipment")
...     sigEquipment = lxml.etree.SubElement(equipment, "SigEquipment")
...     sigEquipment.attrib["fileUID"] = str(row["ID"])
...     sigEquipment.attrib["name"] = ""
```

This iterates over the rows of your DataFrame instance, picks the `"ID"` column for each row and stores that `"ID"` as an attribute `"fileUID"` of each `SigEquipment` node in your XML tree. In lxml, [node attributes are handled as a dictionary](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes-as-a-dict).

You can now print that tree:

```
>>> print(lxml.etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True).decode())
<SchemeData xmlns="Boo">
  <Equipment>
    <SigEquipment fileUID="30734" name=""/>
  </Equipment>
  <Equipment>
    <SigEquipment fileUID="31597" name=""/>
  </Equipment>
</SchemeData>
```

Comment: As simple as that! thank you for help and clearly defining how to resolve the issue.